# Mixing colors correctly: How to avoid the fading effect?

Tags: color, python

I have to mix 2 colors correctly, so that I can produce a word whose letters are colored with 2 colors (say x and y), such that in the beginning, x is dominant on the letters, fading as advancing to the end with the last letter colored the opposite way the first one was.

To make things easier:

```python
def calc(x):
    init_val = 100/(x+1)
    result = []
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        result.append((n:=init_val*i, 100-n))
    return result

while True:
    word = input("Enter the word: ") # criticized
    colors = input("Enter 2 colors (separated by space): ") # Blue Fuchsia
    for number, (mix1, mix2) in enumerate(calc(len(word))):
        print(r"{\color{"+f'{colors.split(" ")[0]}!{mix1}!{colors.split(" ")[1]}!{mix2}'+"}"
              +word[number]+"}")
```

Putting this in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\color{Blue!9.090909090909092!Fuchsia!90.9090909090909}c}
{\color{Blue!18.181818181818183!Fuchsia!81.81818181818181}r}
{\color{Blue!27.272727272727273!Fuchsia!72.72727272727272}i}
{\color{Blue!36.36363636363637!Fuchsia!63.63636363636363}t}
{\color{Blue!45.45454545454546!Fuchsia!54.54545454545454}i}
{\color{Blue!54.54545454545455!Fuchsia!45.45454545454545}c}
{\color{Blue!63.63636363636364!Fuchsia!36.36363636363636}i}
{\color{Blue!72.72727272727273!Fuchsia!27.272727272727266}z}
{\color{Blue!81.81818181818183!Fuchsia!18.181818181818173}e}
{\color{Blue!90.90909090909092!Fuchsia!9.09090909090908}d}

\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

Both `Blue` and `Fuchsia` are dark colors but the mixing leads to a light color at the end. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second set of numbers. You are actually mixing a third color (white) in here. An incomplete mix expression is just an abbreviation for a complete mix expression with the last color = white.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\color{Blue!9.090909090909092!Fuchsia!90.9090909090909}c}
{\color{Blue!18.181818181818183!Fuchsia!81.81818181818181}r}
{\color{Blue!27.272727272727273!Fuchsia!72.72727272727272}i}
{\color{Blue!36.36363636363637!Fuchsia!63.63636363636363}t}
{\color{Blue!45.45454545454546!Fuchsia!54.54545454545454}i}
{\color{Blue!54.54545454545455!Fuchsia!45.45454545454545}c}
{\color{Blue!63.63636363636364!Fuchsia!36.36363636363636}i}
{\color{Blue!72.72727272727273!Fuchsia!27.272727272727266}z}
{\color{Blue!81.81818181818183!Fuchsia!18.181818181818173}e}
{\color{Blue!90.90909090909092!Fuchsia!9.09090909090908}d}


{\color{Blue!9.090909090909092!Fuchsia}c}
{\color{Blue!18.181818181818183!Fuchsia}r}
{\color{Blue!27.272727272727273!Fuchsia}i}
{\color{Blue!36.36363636363637!Fuchsia}t}
{\color{Blue!45.45454545454546!Fuchsia}i}
{\color{Blue!54.54545454545455!Fuchsia}c}
{\color{Blue!63.63636363636364!Fuchsia}i}
{\color{Blue!72.72727272727273!Fuchsia}z}
{\color{Blue!81.81818181818183!Fuchsia}e}
{\color{Blue!90.90909090909092!Fuchsia}d}

\end{document}
```

[image]